# Why does `min-height` on the root capture overflow, but `height` does not?

Tags: html, css

So I recently encountered this scenario where I wanted to create a gradient for a background that would start out as one color, and then extend a different color to the bottom the page. I had initially written some CSS that looks like this:

```css
html {
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom,
        red 50%,
        blue 50%
    );
}
```

This worked at first, until I had content that overflowed the page, and then the gradient repeated itself. I eventually found a solution in changing `height` to `min-height` on the root element, and I had the explanation for why height doesn't work, percentages are based on the containing block, and for the root element that is the "initial containing block" which in this case is the viewport.

What I have not found however, is an answer as to **why** `min-height: 100%` on the root element accounts for the overflow, and that's what I would like answered.

**using height**

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, 
            red 50%, 
            blue 50%
        );
}

#exact-viewport-height {
  height: 101vh;
  opacity: 0.5;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div id="exact-viewport-height">
</div>
```

**using min-height**

```css
html {
  min-height: 100%;
}

body {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, 
            red 50%, 
            blue 50%
        );
}

#exact-viewport-height {
  height: 101vh;
  opacity: 0.5;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div id="exact-viewport-height">
</div>
```

Comment: I should add that my main source for the information I have found has been some combination of MDN and the relevant specifications, but I haven't found any defined behavior for `min-height` that explains this to me yet.

Comment: min-height set a "minimum height" so the height will grow to account for your content.

Comment: I agree that is what happens, why is that different from what setting `height` here does?

Comment: because height and min-height *are* different. inspect the height of the html element in both cases and you will find they are not the same.

Comment: My question is why they are different. What in the spec defines that `min-height: 100%` will encompass all of the content of the page including overflow,  but `height: 100%` will not.

Comment: you don't need to read the spec, the basic MDN definition will explain this. You have two different properties doing diffferent things. Why are you suprised that they are not the same? it has nothing to do with percentage, overflow or anything. height do a thing and min-height a different thing.

Comment: Okay, then please point me at the spot on MDN that explains this difference, the whole point of my question is that I have done all of these things and not found an explanation for this difference.

Comment: One thing I can help point out is that by default html and body are `height:auto`. So, if you only set the `min-height` of the html, the height of `html` won't' be specified and will be following the height of the body, then lower-bounded by `min-height`, 101vh in your case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@TemaniAfif pointed out [overflow-propagation](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-overflow/#overflow-propagation) to answer your question in the comment. To answer your post, the reason you are seeing the different with and without `height:100%` on `html` is because of [background propagation](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-backgrounds-3/#body-background). (`min-height` is not the main reason causing the difference here.)

> For documents whose root element is an HTML HTML element or an XHTML html element [HTML]: if the computed value of background-image on the root element is none and its background-color is transparent, user agents must instead propagate the computed values of the background properties from that element’s first HTML BODY or XHTML body child element. The used values of that BODY element’s background properties are their initial values, and the propagated values are treated as if they were specified on the root element. It is recommended that authors of HTML documents specify the canvas background for the BODY element rather than the HTML element.

In both cases the background properties specified on `body` are actually propagated to `html`. In the first example, `html` has the height of 100vh, so the [size of the linear-gradient](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gradient/linear-gradient#description) is 100vh, causing the background to repeat when the contents of the body is over 100vh.

In the second example the height of `html` is not specified (only specifying `min-height` still leaves height unspecified), so the height of `html` is `height:auto` that depends on its contents' height (`102vh` + default margins), which is the reason the background-image is not repeating.